# In given a line from some file (or stdin) how can i reduce the extra spaces and convert the tabs to single space?

Tags: c, fgets, spaces

In given a line that exist in array. Like in this case:

```
char line[50];
while (fgets(line,50, input_file) != NULL) {
 // how can i do it here..
}
```

How can i reduce all the extra spaces to single space , and to reduce all the tabs (between any two words) to a single space.

**For example:**
In give this line:

```
   a b   abb     ace    ab
```

It's need to be:

```
a b abb ace ab
```

Comment: What have you tried? The little code you posted has a syntax error.

Comment: I edited it. now it's ok?

Comment: In generally, i tried to use 'strtok', but i  don't success to acheive a final solution for this problem.

Comment: @StackUser: It still doesn't show what you've tried. Note that an exercise like this is typically given as homework, which means smart people are reluctant to give any kind of "cut & paste & learn nothing" answer.

Comment: Iterate through the string. Copy characters from one index to another. Replace any tab with space. Advance the target index if the character is not whitespace, or only 1 whitespace. Don't forget to write a new string terminator.

Comment: @Brendan What you want to see? a way that is not working?  If I knew how to solve this problem - I would not ask...

Comment: @StackUser: Yes - some code that doesn't work, that shows that you actually tried to solve the problem and also gives people some idea which part/s of C you're having trouble with (pointers? array indexing? loops?).

Comment: @StackUser: you can accept one o the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *reduce_and_trim(char *s);

int main(void) {
    FILE *input_file = stdin;
    char line[50];
    while (fgets(line,50, input_file) != NULL) {
        printf("'%s'\n", reduce_and_trim(line));
    }
    fclose(input_file);
}

#include <string.h>

char *reduce_and_trim(char *s){
    static const char *whitespaces = " \t\n";//\t:tab, \n:newline, omit \f\r\v
    size_t src = strspn(s, whitespaces);//Trim of the beginning
    size_t des = 0;//destination
    size_t spc = 0;//number of whitespaces

    while(s[src] != '\0'){
        if((spc = strspn(s+src, whitespaces)) != 0){
            src += spc;
            s[des++] = ' ';//reduce spaces
        } else {
            s[des++] = s[src++];
        }
    }
    if(des && s[des-1] == ' ')
        s[des-1] = 0;//Trim of end
    else
        s[des] = 0;

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
char line[50];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, input_file) != NULL) {
    size_t i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isspace((unsigned char)line[i])) {
            while (isspace((unsigned char)line[++i]))
                continue;
            if (line[i] == '\0')
                break;
            if (j != 0)
                line[j++] = ' ';
        }
        line[j++] = line[i];
    }
    line[j] = '\0';
    printf("reduced input: |%s|\n", line);
}
```

Now since this is homework, here are a few extra questions to answer:

- which include files are required?
- why is the cast `(unsigned char)line[i]` needed?
- what will happen if a line longer than 50 bytes is read from `input_file`?
- what is wrong with the previous question?